# Tennants have not been informed that the house has been sold

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, real-estate, rent, fair-housing-acts

I rent a house that the landlord is trying to sell, and the landlord said I have 3 months to leave from when he has found a buyer.

The estate agents have found a buyer, but they have not yet informed me.

I only know the house is sold because they put a 'sold' sign up outside the house

Does that mean I have 3 months from now? or 3 months from whenever they contact me?

Comment: Do you have  a lease?

Comment: I don't know if it's a lease or not. I signed a year long contract, which changed to a rolling monthly one after the year was up. Pretty standard I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's good information at  https://www.gov.uk/private-renting-tenancy-agreements/your-landlord-wants-to-end-your-tenancy.

There are several types of tenancy with different rules, but in all of them, the landlord has to give you a certain amount of notice to move out, and it has to give a specific date.  "Three months from when a buyer is found" doesn't seem to fit that, so I would say you have not yet received formal notice to move out.  This statement may have just been a courtesy to give you more advance warning.  So for instance, if you are in a tenancy that requires two months notice, the landlord may have intended this to mean "I plan to send you formal notice about one month after a buyer is found."  Of course, this is not binding; he could send you formal notice tomorrow if he changes his mind.

As far as I know, the sale of the house is really irrelevant in all of this.  You don't automatically have to move out just because the house is sold; if you're not explicitly told to leave (with appropriate notice) then you don't have to, and you'll just start paying your rent to the new landlord.  If you have a fixed-term tenancy, then the sale of the house doesn't shorten it.

I am not sure what the point is of getting angry at the estate agents.  Your tenancy is a matter between you and your landlord, and the estate agents have nothing to do with it.  They work for your landlord, not for you.

Comment: I thought the estate agents were responsible for making us aware. As you have pointed out, that is the responsibility of the landlord. Thanks for your advice, it has greatly helped